# How to get value from Select/Option component from Ant design

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, antd

I want to retrieve the value from my selection so I can make post requests. I have no problem getting from text input, but for some reason I can't get it from the drop down menu select. I end up getting a 
`"TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined"`

Here is the code I am using.

```
import React from "react";
import { Form, Input, Button, Select } from "antd";

const { Option } = Select;

class ItemForm extends React.Component {

  handleFormSubmit = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const name = event.target.elements.name.value;
    const description = event.target.elements.description.value;
    const category = event.target.elements.category.value;
    console.log(name, description, this.refs.category.value);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Form onSubmit={this.handleFormSubmit}>
          <Form.Item label="Form Layout" />
          <Form.Item label="Product Name">
            <Input name="name" placeholder="Ex: Organic Apple..." />
          </Form.Item>
          <Form.Item label="Description">
            <Input name="description" placeholder="Ex: Juicy organic apples!" />
          </Form.Item>
          <Form.Item label="Category">
            <Select name="category" placeholder="Please select a category">
              <Option value="Fruit">Fruit</Option>
              <Option value="Vegetable">Vegetable</Option>
              <Option value="Poultry">Poultry</Option>
            </Select>
          </Form.Item>
          <Form.Item>
            <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit">
              Submit
            </Button>
          </Form.Item>
        </Form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default ItemForm;
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use `onChange` which is fired when the value of the select changes. [antd select documentation](https://ant.design/components/select/)

```
<Form.Item label="Category">
  <Select 
    onChange={(value) => {
      alert(value)
    }} 
    name="category" 
    placeholder="Please select a category">
      <Option value="Fruit">Fruit</Option>
      <Option value="Vegetable">Vegetable</Option>
      <Option value="Poultry">Poultry</Option>
  </Select>
</Form.Item>
```

[working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-4extub?file=ItemForm.js)

Comment: Oh I see. So I'm assuming there's no "lazy" way to do it (the way I did it for the input text) and need to do an onChange trigger. Thank you very much.

Comment: Oh I had to add category as a const outside of the class (so on change i could do this.category = value). Is this the correct way? Or is there a better way.

Comment: It should be inside the class like `category = other`, without `const`.

Comment: help! select tag is not working when you put it inside a div.. the data is undefined

Answer (score 3):

Something similar to the classic javascript approach, you intended to use, could be use `getFieldValue`.
But coupling to coherent `createRef` , `Form` and `Form.Item` as below.

*When getting values, remember to reference the `Form.Item` name and not the `Input` one* ;-)

I have created a [sandbox demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/billowing-forest-um5s6) hoping other people will enjoy or contribute.

```
import React from "react";
import { Form, Input, Button, Select } from "antd";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "antd/dist/antd.css";
import "./index.css"; //export default ItemForm;

const { Option } = Select;

class ItemForm extends React.Component {
  formRef = React.createRef();

  handleFormSubmit = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log("All field values", this.formRef.current.getFieldsValue());
    const name = this.formRef.current.getFieldValue("productName"); //OLD event.target.elements.name.value;
    const description = this.formRef.current.getFieldValue("description"); //OLD event.target.elements.description.value;
    const category = this.formRef.current.getFieldValue("category"); //OLD event.target.elements.category.value;
    console.log(name, description, category);
    alert(`${name}, ${description}, ${category}`);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Form ref={this.formRef} onSubmit={this.handleFormSubmit}>
          <Form.Item label="Form Layout (Form.Item-createRef-getFieldValue Example)" />
          <Form.Item label="Product Name" name="productName">
            <Input name="name" placeholder="Ex: Organic Apple..." />
          </Form.Item>
          <Form.Item label="Description" name="description">
            <Input name="description" placeholder="Ex: Juicy organic apples!" />
          </Form.Item>
          <Form.Item label="Category" name="category">
            <Select name="category" placeholder="Please select a category">
              <Option value="Fruit">Fruit</Option>
              <Option value="Vegetable">Vegetable</Option>
              <Option value="Poultry">Poultry</Option>
            </Select>
          </Form.Item>
          <Form.Item>
            <Button
              type="primary"
              htmlType="submit"
              onClick={this.handleFormSubmit}
            >
              Submit
            </Button>
          </Form.Item>
        </Form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
ReactDOM.render(<ItemForm />, document.getElementById("container"));
```

Answer (score 2):

Managed it by using onChange as shown below this.

```
state = {
    status: ""
  };

          <Form.Item label="Status">
            <Select
              name="status"
              onChange={value => {
                this.setState({ status: value });
              }}
              placeholder="Please choose the status"
            >
              <Option value="new">New</Option>
              <Option value="open">Open</Option>
              <Option value="rejected">Rejected</Option>
              <Option value="deferred">Deferred</Option>
              <Option value="reopened">Reopened</Option>
            </Select>
          </Form.Item>
```

Answer (score 1):

unlike what you would expect, in Ant Design Select you can't get the value by calling:

```
onChange={(e)=>console.log(e.target.value)}
```

no. instead you get the value directly by just accessing the event itself, like this:

```
onChange={(e)=>console.log(e)}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this as follows. (Works fine for Antd)

```
 <Select
    onChange={(text, index) => {
    console.log(index.children);
    }}
 >
```

Answer (score 0):

A better and cleaner way to avoid this issue is to define all the form values and labels in an array and pass it into the . Declare or use an onChange event and store the value of the event in your state.